# datagridview Cells and comboboxes

Tags: c#, datagridview

Hello people :)
I want to bind my comboboxes to dgv cells . when dgv cells will be resize change size automaticli comboboxes size . and want to dock on above dgv cells
how can i make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your problem is not cleared much.

Here I am adding another answer.
As you have said in one of your reply that you want to resize "yourComboboxColumn" on changing the size of "Products" Column

Put this Code: In the **ColumnWidthChange** event

```
 if (DGV.Columns.Contains("yourColumn") && e.Column == dataGridView1.Columns["Products"])
 {
      DGV.Columns["yourColumn"].Width = e.Column.Width;
 }
```

**Edited:**
To bind data of your `combobox` to `ComboboxColumn` do this

```
((DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) DGV.Columns["yourColumn"]).DataSource = cb.Items;
//"yourColumn" is the comboBoxColumn in DGV
// cb is the ComboBox which contains Items
```

Comment: thank you :) its works fine. and can you tell me how i can bind combobox to dgv column?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add Column of a type **[DataGridViewComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx)** to DataGridView and bind it with your DataSource
2. To resize your Columns on Changing the size of DGV set AutoSizeColumnMode to Fill

   ```
           DGV.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
   ```

**Edited:**

In the **ColumnWidthChange** event of **DGV** put below code

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in DGV.Columns) //DGV is your dataGridView
  {
      column.Width = e.Column.Width;
  }
```

Comment: No i mean i want that my combob box will resize when datagridview column "Products" will be resize. and get same size as column

Comment: there can be more than one column and each may have different size. So, tell which Column?

Comment: there is 7 combobox and 7 columns i want to do all

Comment: Do you want to change size of all columns if any of them is resized? and set them all of same size?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for my bad English.